# How do I write this cross apply query in LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following tables:

```
create table TableA (
    Id int primary key identity,
    Key int not null
)

create table TableB (
    Id int primary key identity,
    TableA_Id int not null foreign key references TableA(Id),
    Value varchar(80) not null
)
```

I would like to write the following query in LINQ-to-SQL using lambda notation:

```
select TableA.Key, b.Value
from TableA
cross apply (
    select top 10 TableB.Value
    from TableB
    where TableA.Id = TableB.TableA_Id
    order by TableB.Value
) b
where TableA.Key between 0 and 999
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var query = from a in context.TableA
            from b in context.TableB
                             .Where(x => x.TableA_Id == a.Id)
                             .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
                             .Take(10)
            where a.Key >= 0 && a.Key <= 999
            select new
            {
              a.Key,
              b.Value,
            };
```

Comment: why i cannot use a in where condition for b?

Answer (score 1):

//get latest activity info for every user

```
 var query = ActivityRepository.Where(p => p.iAction > -1 && 

   userIds.Contains(p.iSellerId)).GroupBy(c => c.iSellerId).Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(cc => cc.dBeginTime).First()).Select(a => new ActivityInfo

        {
            ActivityId = a.iActivityId,
            StartTime = a.dBeginTime,
            SellerId = a.iSellerId,
            EndTime = a.dEndTime,
            ActivityName = a.sName,
        });
```

this code will generate outer apply sytax.