# How to transform cross apply with select top to linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have a complex query that must be transforemd into linq. I have no idea how to convert cross apply with select top 1 statement and select sum. Here's the query:

```
 SELECT C.LASTNAME, C.FIRSTNAME, U.IMP_REPORT_NAME, C.CLIENTID, U.IMP_USER_REPORT_ID, U.IMP_REPORT_DATE, U.EMPLOYEEID, TBL_RATINGS.TOTAL AS TOTAL_RATING 
 FROM CLIENTS AS C

 CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 IMP_USER_REPORT_ID, IMP_REPORT_NAME, IMP_REPORT_DATE, EMPLOYEEID 
 FROM IMPORT_USER_REPORTS 
 AND CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID 
 AND IMP_REPORT_DATE <= @fromDate
 ORDER BY IMP_REPORT_DATE DESC, IMP_USER_REPORT_ID DESC 
 ) AS U 

 CROSS APPLY ( SELECT SUM(ANSWER_RATING) AS TOTAL 
 FROM IMPORT_USER_ANSWERS 
 WHERE IMPORT_USER_ANSWERS.IMP_USER_REPORT_ID = U.IMP_USER_REPORT_ID 
 ) AS TBL_RATINGS 

 WHERE C.ACTIVE = 1 
 ORDER BY LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
```

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

CROSS APPLY is similar to a JOIN requiring a more complex condition, so [WHERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb919081(v=vs.90).aspx) can be used as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787482/how-do-i-write-this-cross-apply-query-in-linq-to-sql).