# LINQ Expression for CROSS APPLY two levels deep

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

Fairly new to LINQ and am trying to figure out how to write a particular query.  I have a database where each CHAIN consists of one or more ORDERS and each ORDER consists of one or more PARTIALS.  The database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Chain
(
ID         int            NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1),
Ticker     nvarchar(6)    NOT NULL,
Company    nvarchar(128)  NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Order]
(
ID      int             NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   IDENTITY(1,1),
Chart   varbinary(max)  NULL,
-- Relationships
Chain   int             NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.[Order] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_Chain 
    FOREIGN KEY (Chain) REFERENCES dbo.Chain ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

CREATE TABLE Partial
(
ID           int     NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1),
Date         date    NOT NULL,
Quantity     int     NOT NULL,
Price        money   NOT NULL,
Commission   money   NOT NULL,
-- Relationships
[Order]       int     NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Partial ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Partial_Order
    FOREIGN KEY ([Order]) REFERENCES dbo.[Order] ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I want to retrieve the chains, ordered by the earliest date among all the partials of all the orders for each particular chain.  In T-SQL I would write the query as this:

```
SELECT p.DATE, c.*
FROM   CHAIN c
CROSS  APPLY
(
    SELECT DATE = MIN(p.Date)
    FROM   PARTIAL p
    JOIN   [ORDER] o
      ON   p.[ORDER] = o.ID
    WHERE  o.CHAIN = c.ID
) AS p
ORDER BY p.DATE ASC
```

I have an Entity Framework context that contains a DbSet<Chain>, a DbSet<Order>, and a DbSet<Partial>.  How do I finish this statement to get the result I want?:

```
IEnumerable<Chain> chains = db.Chains
                              .Include(c => c.Orders.Select(o => o.Partials))
                              .[WHAT NOW?]
```

Thank you!

Comment: This might be of help : [linq cross apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787482/how-do-i-write-this-cross-apply-query-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: See following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .[WHAT NOW?]

```
.OrderBy(c => c.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.Partials).Min(p => p.Date))
```

Here `c.Orders` does join `Chain` to `Order`, while `o.SelectMany(o => o.Partials)` does join `Order` to `Partial`. Once you have access to `Partial` records, you can use any aggregate function, like `Min(p => p.Date)` in your case.

Comment: Ah, okay, I get it.  The SelectMany is one of the more confusing expressions at first glance, but your explanation makes it very clear.  Thank you, Ivan!